# Вывод порядкового номера буквы в приложении

Tags: c++-cli

Код по выводу порядкового номера нажатой буквы работает в консольном приложении, но не работает в приложении под винду. Нужно вывести порядковый номер буквы, нажатой на клавиатуре.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    while (true) {
        switch (toupper(_getch())){
        case 'F': cout << "1 "; break;
        case ',': cout << "2 "; break;
        // another keys
        }
    }
}
```

Вот код из виндоус приложения:

```cpp
private: System::Void textBox1_KeyDown(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        switch (toupper(_getch())) {
        case 'F': textBox2->AppendText("1 "); break;
        case ",": textBox2->AppendText("2 "); break;
        // another keys
        }
    }
```

При вводе "А", должно вывести 1, так как А - первая буква алфавита, при "Я" - 33.

Comment: Потому что в GUI вам код клавиши передается в параметре e. Вы пытаетесь применить консольную функцию там где она не работает. Вот пример https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keydown?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: И в чём проблема написать case 'A' - "1 " и так далее?